# Why are there two magnon propagators in Ferromagnetic system?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, many-body

I am confused that the authors of ref.[1,2] defined two magnon propagators in the *ferromagnetic* system with magnon-phonon coupling (which is similar to electron-phonon coupling). They defined temperature magnon green's function as:

$$G^{0}(k,\tau)=-\langle T a_{k}(\tau)a^{\dagger}_{k}(0) \rangle,\\
\tilde {G} ^{0}(k,\tau)=-\langle T a_{k}^{\dagger}(\tau)a_{k}(0) \rangle,$$ 
where $a_{k}$ is magnon operator, T is the imaginary time ordering operator.

When they calculate magnon self-energy, they use $G$ and $\tilde G$, but when they calculate phonon self-energy, they just use $G$.

**Question: Is it necessary to introduce the $\tilde{G}^{0}(k,\tau)$? Because $G^{0}(k,\tau)=\tilde{G}^{0}(k,-\tau)$**

Why not introduce similar propagator in fermion system (such as electron-phonon problem)?

refs:

1.L.M.Woods, PhysRevB.65.014409,

2.T.M.Cheng, Physics Letters A 353 (2006) 431–438.